# How to avoid: "blockingToByteString is a blocking and unsafe operation"

Tags: scala, playframework, ws-client

In my Play Project I want to get the Message Digest of a File that I get from a REST Service.

Service call:

```
ws.url("deployment/data/idResource").withMethod("GET").stream
```

From the Response (`WSResponse`) I extract the body like:

```
response.bodyAsBytes.toByteBuffer.array()
```

This gives me this warning:

```
p.a.l.w.a.StandaloneAhcWSClient$ - blockingToByteString is a blocking and unsafe operation!
```

Is there a way to avoid this warning.

As mentioned in the end I need an `Array[Byte]` for the Message Digest.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638727/4965515

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a little bit late but I had the same problem and there was no answer, so here it is:

call `execute` instead of `stream` like

```
ws.url("deployment/data/idResource").withMethod("GET").execute
```

Then you can read WSResponse as json / string etc. without blocking warning