# Akka Stream Exception Thrown When Downloading File From S3

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am trying to download a file from S3 using the following code:

```scala
     wsClient
      .url(url)
      .withMethod("GET")
      .withHttpHeaders(my_headers: _*)
      .withRequestTimeout(timeout)
      .stream()
          .map {             
            case AhcWSResponse(underlying) =>
                  underlying.bodyAsBytes
              }
```

When I run this I get the following exception:

```scala
    akka.stream.StreamLimitReachedException: limit of 13 reached
```

Is this because I am using `bodyAsBytes`? What does this error mean ? I also see this warning message which is probably related:

```scala
 blockingToByteString is a blocking and unsafe operation!
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because if you use `stream()`, you need to consume the source using `bodyAsSource`. It is important to do so or it would otherwise backpressure the connection. `body` or `bodyAsBytes` are implemented and do consume the source but for some reason the implementor decided to let you know that you should have used `execute()` instead of `stream()` by limiting the body to 13 ByteStrings and 50ms timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting StreamLimitReachedExpcetion because the number of incoming elements is larger than max.

```
val MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE = 100

// OK. Future will fail with a `StreamLimitReachedException`
// if the number of incoming elements is larger than max
val limited: Future[Seq[String]] =
  mySource.limit(MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE).runWith(Sink.seq)

// OK. Collect up until max-th elements only, then cancel upstream
val ignoreOverflow: Future[Seq[String]] =
  mySource.take(MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE).runWith(Sink.seq)
```

You can find more information about streaming process [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html)

Comment: what is an element in this case? is it a single byte?